# Favorite questions and answers from the first quarter of 2013

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from January 1st 2013 through March 31st 2013.

I'm going to compile list to post to the blog.

This will be similar to the QOTW (http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/) posts only it would be more of a quarterly thing.

Answer (score 2):

A recent question I thought particular good (and with a good answer): [Where'd those guys on the Millennium Falcon go?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33517/whered-those-guys-on-the-millenium-falcon-go)

Answer (score 2):

I learned a lot from this question and it surprised me with a topic that I'd never considered before. The accepted answer composed by @MattPatterson & @Iszi is also awesome and contains very fun, informative links.

Q&A: [Which actor has portrayed the most distinct roles in the Star Trek universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31810/which-actor-has-portrayed-the-most-distinct-roles-in-the-star-trek-universe)

@DanielRoseman has put up great Tolkien answers. For instance,
A: [Why did Boromir take so long to reach Rivendell?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33741/why-did-boromir-take-so-long-to-reach-rivendell/33748#33748)

Answer (score 1):

For now, the posts I find particularly noteworthy and partly underrated are

### Questions

- [Why is Janeway an Admiral and Picard is not?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31771/2565)
- [Was LCARS derived from an open-source codebase?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/33444/2565)

### Answers

- [How many crewmen/women die in the original series of Star Trek?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/32483/2565)
- [Lost Star Wars fan-made video](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/32718/2565)
- [What is the original context of this Spock video clip?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/32014/2565)

Comment: OB-1 question is from 2011.

Comment: Oops. I was going through my upvotes from January through March and apparently neglected to check the date on the post. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I Made 3 query to help select nominees :

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/01/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/01/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/01/01)

[Why was Scrooge chosen for redemption?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32411/why-was-scrooge-chosen-for-redemption)  and [What are Gandalf's powers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29164/what-are-gandalfs-powers) seem goods candidates.

Answer (score 0):

[Can a House-elf be made a Secret Keeper?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32445/could-a-house-elf-be-made-into-a-secret-keeper) asked by **Fen1ks** on 3/2/13

[Why would a Shrinking Solution turn Neville's toad into a tadpole rather than a small toad?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32956/why-would-shrinking-solution-turn-a-frog-into-a-tadpole-and-not-a-small-size-fro) asked by **DVK** on 3/14/13

[Charms and Enchantments Conundrum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32929/charmsenchantments-conundrum) asked by **Fen1ks** on 3/13/13

[How do the wandmakers get the cores into the wands?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33468/how-do-the-wand-makers-get-the-cores-into-the-wands/33737#33737) asked by **Major Stackings** on 3/26/13, and featuring **John O** and his now absconded drill press.

[What elements of Arthurian legend are adopted in *Harry Potter*?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33717/what-elements-of-arthurian-legend-are-adopted-in-harry-potter) asked by **Inception** on 4/1/13

[Steampunk energy sources: What are they and how are they obtained?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/steampunk-energy-sources-what-are-they-and-how-are-they-obtained) asked by **Alenanno** on 4/3/13

[Why did Lily's enchantments work for Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32157/why-did-lilys-enchantments-work-for-voldemort/32158#32158) asked by **a Slytherin** on 2/24/13

[What parts of *Half-Blood Prince* were originally written for *Chamber of Secrets*?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28777/what-parts-of-half-blood-prince-were-originally-written-for-chamber-of-secrets) asked by **Izkata** on 1/1/13

HONORABLE MENTION:

[Did Mad-Eye Moody lose a buttock?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34383/did-mad-eye-moody-lose-a-buttock) asked by **ZOMG** on 4/17/13

[image]