# Favorite Questions and Answers from 2nd Quarter of 2013

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2013 through June 30th 2013.

I'm going to compile list to post to the blog.

This will be similar to the first quarter post http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2013/04/highlights-from-2013-1st-quarter/

I'm posting this about 10 days early, that should be enough time to start getting something together and allow for late entries.

Answer (score 6):

Using [the query I made last quarter](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2877/45) :

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/04/01)

### Based on the **June 30 2013** data dump

The must popular were :

1. [Who is torturing Theon Greyjoy and why?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35547/who-is-torturing-theon-greyjoy-and-why) with 25,925 views
2. [Is Iron Man 3's ending based on any canonical source?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34770/is-iron-man-3s-ending-based-in-any-canonical-source) with 13971 views
3. [What do the White Walkers do with the baby boy gifts from Craster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35191) with 9224 views.

The must voted question were :

1. [What is the origin of the "Riker Chair Maneuver"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35410/what-is-the-origin-of-the-riker-chair-maneuver) (57)
2. [Why did the Fellowship not choose to pass the Misty Mountains further north or south?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35522/why-did-the-fellowship-not-choose-to-pass-the-misty-mountains-further-north-or-s) (44)
3. [Does the death penalty exist in comics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37084) (40)
4. [Was Picard speaking French and being translated the entire time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34582/was-picard-speaking-french-and-being-translated-the-entire-time) (40)
5. [Why would Dumbledore encourage people to call Voldemort Voldemort instead of Tom Riddle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35639/why-would-dumbledore-encourage-people-to-call-voldemort-voldemort-instead-of-tom) (39)

The must voted answers were :

1. [Does the death penalty exist in comics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37084) (65)
2. [What is the origin of the "Riker Chair Maneuver"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35410) (61)
3. [Was Picard speaking French and being translated the entire time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34582) (47)
4. [Can Starfleet doctors make Captain rank?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34116) (44)
5. [Short story about Tibetan monks who want to know the name of God?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35303) (44)
6. [Why would Dumbledore encourage people to call Voldemort Voldemort instead of Tom Riddle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35639) (42)
7. [Why does Carol Marcus not recognize Khan in The Wrath of Khan?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36272) (41)

Comment: +1 for the Riker Chair Maneuver

Comment: +1 for "Why would Dumbledore encourage people to call Voldemort Voldemort instead of Tom Riddle?"

Comment: The recently-posted question [Does death penalty exist in comics](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37084/does-the-death-penalty-exist-in-comics) modify both your "must voted question" and "must voted answers" ladders. Can we link our own questions/answers ? This one would be my favorite

Comment: @Kalissar The data is updated more regularly than in the past. (it was updated the 23 of June, so it's probably updated weekly.) I will update this answer at the end of the month.

Comment: Updated with the June 30 2013 data dump.

Answer (score 4):

I thought this one was really interesting:

[How did the Death Star manage the debris after exploding a planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36962/how-did-the-death-star-manage-the-debris-after-exploding-a-planet)

At first glance it seemed like something that may be semi-unanswerable, and DVK comes in with what looks like the best we're going to get.  Then along comes Gorchestopher H with an absolutely *awesome* answer based on distance and volume, DVK (rightly) questions it, that gets me thinking "hold on, we should be able to work this out" and the end result is a distance range that supports Gorchestopher H's answer and is entirely based on the movie and movie alone (unquestionable in canon terms, in other words).

That was fun to participate in and was a great example of a slightly left-of-field approach that didn't go near the usual sources but yet produced a great answer that's not open to further questioning.

Comment: Definitely one of the best.

Answer (score 3):

Question:

[Did Mazer Rackham have a tattooed face in Ender's Game book?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35024/did-mazer-rackham-have-a-tattooed-face-in-enders-game-book/35086)

the only thing missing are hand drawn circles :)

Answer (score 3):

Answer (to my question, but the answer is fabulous) :

[Does the death penalty exist in comics ?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37090/13418)

As I say in my comment, both in-universe and out-of-universe reasons, appropriated examples for each one, detailed classification of described cases, taking account of question exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Question (and my answer to it:)

[Who became Emperor of the Galactic Empire after death of Emperor Palpatine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34407/who-became-emperor-of-the-galactic-empire-after-death-of-emperor-palpatine)

A nice set of highlights of TGFFA history from a certain angle, across many EU arcs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37280/3804) and [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37286/3804), about the Dalek Civil War.

It covers the new and old series as well as Davros' involvement in great detail.

Answer (score -1):

I'll toot my own horn.

Answer:

[Why was Mace Windu Surprised when Jango Fett was Decapitated?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36118/why-was-mace-windu-surprised-when-jango-fett-was-decapitated/36127#36127)

Tons of screenshots, embedded Youtube, canon quoting galore.