# Favorite Questions and Answers from third quarter of 2013

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from **July 1st 2013 through September 30th 2013**.

I'm going to compile list to post to the blog. This will be the same format as the last two quarterly blogs.

Answer (score 3):

Using [the queries I made 2 quarter ago](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2877/45) :

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)

### Based on the **Sept. 22 2013** data dump

The must popular were :

1. [In Star Trek, does the transporter conserve the momentum of transported objects?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39295) with 10,323 views.
2. [In which order should I start watching Star Trek?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37689) with 9,097 views.
3. [Why is Arwen dying?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40031) with 8,603 views.

The must voted question were :

1. [Can you tell my robot to kill itself? (Three Laws)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40718) (41)
2. [Why didn't Dumbledore realise that Moody had been replaced?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39312) (36)
3. [Did the Ring Bearers and Gimli die in Valinor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39920) (26)

The must voted answers were :

1. [Can you tell my robot to kill itself? (Three Laws)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40718) (68)
2. [Who Inherited Bag End?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37949) (51)
3. [What type of addressing does Tony Stark use in Iron Man 3?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40047) (45)
4. [Is Trantor Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37977) (43)

Answer (score 1):

My favorites are two of the LotR questions DavRob60 listed from his queries:

- [Did the Ring Bearers or Gimli die in Valinor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39920/1359)
- [Who Inherited Bag End?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37949/1359)

Both are good questions, and both received excellent answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to add this late answer (Jul 3) on a first quarter question :

[What is the significance of the reversed colours of imperial and rebellion lasers compared to lightsabres?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/37716/45)

> [image: wonderful!]

Comment: Yes, that one was really surprising for me. I kinda feel a bit bad for not having accepted it yet, but I was hoping for some sort of a more official confirmation. Great answer, anyway :)